# remove values from search result in catalog search top search box

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch

i have tried core/Mage/catalogSearch/Helper/Data.php 
and ResultController.php in Controller and Query.php in model but couldn't find code so i can fix it   here is snapshot attached which i have to remove .. 
[image]

Comment: Are you looking to remove the auto-suggest option ?

Comment: NO I JUST WANT TO REMOVE EXTRA NUMERIC VALUE COME WITH SUGGESTION  AS SHOWN IN SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 2):

you can enable show template and show block name 
in adminhtml.

`admin->system->configuration->for develop`

change you webstore to `Default store view`;

end emable options `template hints` and `hints block` and save your configuration.

after you can update search result page, and see your path to template.
if template location in core directory themes, you need copy this file to your theme. And search this link and comment...

Comment: i used display none in style 'THE LAST OPTION'

Answer (score 0):

Go to system -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search and (Show Autocomplete Results Count) select No in dropdown. This is work for me.